# svn branch/trunk using the some of the same files

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

I am running a project that has the option of using either .json files or java RESTful service (getting the data from a database.)  I have the about 6 RESTful specific files in my trunk and 6 specific .json files in my branches folder. However other than those 6 files, both the trunk and branch folders have hundreds of other files that are identical to each other.

My question is, is there a way for me to keep those 6 files separate, but have both the trunk and the branch run off of the same hundred files that are identical? Maybe through SVN somehow?

I know it's confusing. But since those 6 files are the same I can't ever merge them back together, and don't plan to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SVN externals in order to link shared between branches files from single common location. This is slightly non-canonical solution (I added externals definition at `/branches` node directly), but - it works!

```
>svn pl -R -v
Properties on 'branches':
  svn:externals
    file:///Z:/Repo/trunk JSON
    file:///Z:/Repo/Vendor/JSON JSON/Interface
    file:///Z:/Repo/trunk REST
    file:///Z:/Repo/Vendor/REST REST/Interface
```

[image: Nested Externals]

As result:

- root of REST|JSON branches is link to the same `/trunk` (you modify common files only once - in trunk)
- Subdir `Interface` in each case linked to *different* "implementations", which I placed outside ordinary tree

In 6 different files are not in common directory, you have just to replace 1 directory-externals by 6 file-externals (and use 1.6+ SVN)